# Spring Autowire issue with Runnable JAR. Specific to Autowire JPA Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-data-jpa, executable-jar

I am building a self contained application(JAR including all required libraries) to validate some of the database operations. When I tried to build annotation based application, it worked fine in Eclipse but from JAR its giving Bean not found exception.

Following are my main pain areas.

How to enable JPA repository class autowire enabled ?
I would be able to explicitly register each classes except JPA repository as its an Interface.

Any help on this topic would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are creating a spring boot application, spring boot would prepare the required infrastructure to autowire the Spring JPA repositories, you do not have to autowire the JpaRepository but you have to autowire the Repository in your code that extends the JpaRepository. For example:

```
public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository{}
```

you will have to autowire YourRepository and spring will provide a `SimpleJpaRepository` as an injection.

Comment: Thanks Naresh for the update. This is not Spring boot app, I am trying to build self contained jar  with all dependant jars and  autowiring is for custom repository.